# meshが重なって作成されてしまう

Tags: r

jpmeshライブラリを使用して幾つかのメッシュを取り出したのですが、一部に10mほどメッシュの重なりが出てしまいました。一旦st_write_dbで格納してQGIS側でも確認したのですが、同じ状況でした。ご指摘いただければと思います。
お忙しいところ大変恐縮ですが、どうぞよろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(jpmesh)
library(mapview)

mesh_list<-data.frame(x=c(533945191,533945192,533945193,533945194,533945291,533945292,533945293,533945294,533946101,533946102,533946103,533946104,533946201,533946202,533946203,533946204))

do.call(rbind,pmap(mesh_list,~export_mesh(meshcode = .x) %>% st_sf() %>% mutate(ID=.x))) %>% 
 st_set_crs(4326) %>% 
 mapview(z="ID")
```

Comment: こちらのパッケージ開発に携わる者です。ご利用くださりましてありがとうございます。

こちらの問題ですが、手元でもメッシュの重なりを確認いたしました。
重なりが発生してしまうのはパッケージの方の処理に問題があるためなようです。
開発版のリポジトリであるGitHubのissuesへ問題を報告しておきました。 https://github.com/uribo/jpmesh/issues/20


解決方針の見通しはある程度ついているので、近日中に問題の解決を行えると思います。
その際、改めてこちらでご報告させていただければと存じます。
問題のご報告、感謝いたします。こちらの不手際で申し訳ありません。

Comment: こちらこそブログも含め毎回助かっております。返信ありがとうございます、export_meshesという関数もあるんですね,勉強になりました。よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 精度の問題で微妙な重複が残っているのですが、報告いただいたような問題を解決するように修正しました。`remotes::install_github("uribo/jpmesh")` 等での開発版の利用を行っていただけますでしょうか。

Comment: 御対応ありがとうございます、export_meshが修正されていることが確認できました！、"export_meshes"はdo.callが不要なので便利そうですが当面export_meshで対応させていただきます。ありがとうございました